Render multiple pixels in SDL2 C
I've recently been trying to make an VGA terminal in C using SDL2.
So far, I've rendered pixels by using this function here:
void update(SDL_Renderer** ren){
   for(u16 y = 0; y < 480; y++){
      for(u16 x = 0; x < 640; x++){
         u32 col = getVGAColor(display[(y * 480) + x]);
         u8 r = (col >> 24) & 0xFF;
         u8 g = (col >> 16) & 0xFF;
         u8 b = (col >> 8) & 0xFF;
         SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*ren, r, g, b, 255);
         SDL_RenderDrawPoint(*ren, x, y);
         SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
      }
   }
}

I also tried using surfaces and textures, but so far the only answers I've been getting are written in SDL3.
Is there a faster way to write this update function?

Hmmm, should not (y * 480) + x be (y * 640) + x?

Yes, you should use a surface and store everything in it directly. Don't copy all pixels every frame.
